# FileLoadException with Newtonsoft.Json trying to use MapHttpRoute in 4.5.1 WebForms

Tags: c#, webforms, json.net, asp.net-web-api2, assemblybinding

I added a 2.1 Web API Controller Class to my 4.5.1 WebForms application.  Afterwards, my packages.config looked like:

```
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.2.7" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.7" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.7" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.2.7" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="12.0.2" targetFramework="net451" />
```

My Web.config looks like this:

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding appliesTo="v2.0.50727" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-12.0.0.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

I was following the instructions from this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/using-web-api-with-aspnet-web-forms

I added the following to `Application_Start`:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

However, when I run and it attempts to run this line, I get the following error:

```
System.IO.FileLoadException
  HResult=0x80131040
  Message=Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
  Source=System.Net.Http.Formatting
  StackTrace:
   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter..ctor()
   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter..ctor()
   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.MediaTypeFormatterCollection.CreateDefaultFormatters()
   at System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration.DefaultFormatters(HttpConfiguration config)
   at System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration..ctor(HttpRouteCollection routes)
   at System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.<>c.<CreateConfiguration>b__11_0()
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
   at System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.get_Configuration()
   at System.Web.Http.RouteCollectionExtensions.MapHttpRoute(RouteCollection routes, String name, String routeTemplate, Object defaults, Object constraints, HttpMessageHandler handler)
   at System.Web.Http.RouteCollectionExtensions.MapHttpRoute(RouteCollection routes, String name, String routeTemplate, Object defaults)
   at Modeler.Global.Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\BTR\Evolution\Websites\ESS\DRA\Global.asax.cs:line 13
```

I've tried removing the binding redirect info in web.config and received the same error.

**Update**

Originally, my library dlls referenced 11.0.2 of Newtonsoft.  I updated them to 12.0.2 in an attempt to make things work which didn't.  So I put all my projects (including the web site) back to 11.0.2 and still have the same problem.  But I wanted to note, that I tested in a Webforms project without referencing my library dlls which already had a 12.0.3 reference to Newtonsoft and it worked.  So there is something going on with the fact that I have dependent dlls that reference Newtonsoft, but I don't know what it could be.

All reference 11.0.2 and when the site is running (if I comment out call to `MapHttpRoute`), `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` correctly shows:

`{Newtonsoft.Json, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed}`

**Fusion Log**

```
*** Assembly Binder Log Entry  (4/16/2021 @ 10:44:07 AM) ***

The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x80131040. No description available.

Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/BTR/Evolution/Websites/ESS/DRA/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\BTR\Evolution\Websites\ESS\DRA\bin
LOG: Dynamic Base = C:\Users\terry.aney\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\66fd6d3a
LOG: Cache Base = C:\Users\terry.aney\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\vs\66fd6d3a
LOG: AppName = 92fcbfc0
Calling assembly : System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=5.2.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\BTR\Evolution\Websites\ESS\DRA\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Users\terry.aney\OneDrive\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed
LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/terry.aney/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/vs/66fd6d3a/92fcbfc0/Newtonsoft.Json.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/terry.aney/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/vs/66fd6d3a/92fcbfc0/Newtonsoft.Json/Newtonsoft.Json.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/BTR/Evolution/Websites/ESS/DRA/bin/Newtonsoft.Json.DLL.
LOG: Assembly download was successful. Attempting setup of file: C:\BTR\Evolution\Websites\ESS\DRA\bin\Newtonsoft.Json.dll
LOG: Entering download cache setup phase.
LOG: Assembly Name is: Newtonsoft.Json, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Major Version
ERR: The assembly reference did not match the assembly definition found.
ERR: Setup failed with hr = 0x80131040.
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.
```

Comment: Could it be because your `bindingRedirect` goes up to 12.0.0.0 but the package version is 12.0.2

Comment: Not sure why package manager does that, but I did try: `<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-12.0.2.0" newVersion="12.0.2" />` and it didn't work either.

Comment: Don't know how it happened (and I've seen this same comment on other questions with same json.net issue), but I just kept trying to uninstall/reinstall and it finally worked.  Surely something changed that I'm not recalling, but my last step was to use nuget manager, remove webapi and json.net, then resinstall webapi (which installed 6.0.4 json.net), then upgrade json.net to 11.0.2 and it worked.  But I had done that before and it didn't work.  The joys of dll hell.